# How do you import a reference to a dart file when you only know the file name? Extension methods and others

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

To import a file in Dart (using IntelliJ) I will usually use start typing the name of a function, class or variable and select enter.  Alternatively I might type the name of the class and press alt+enter on it.  This will then give me an option to import the file reference.

For extension methods this doesn't work and sometimes I know the name of the package (file) I want to import but can't remember the name of the function.

Is there a way to use the filename to lookup and insert an import statement with the full package address?

## Edit

Unfortunately my originally accepted answer doesn't always work.  For example with extension methods.  I'm trying to add a reference and it seems impossible to do without typing the full reference to the extension.

[image]

### Edit2

Found out there is an open issue to fix this

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40365

Comment: If I am writing `import 'som...'` and ctrl+space for auto-complete I can get IntelliJ to get me suggestion across all packages imported with pubspec and files across my project. If the file is inside a package, it will automatically insert the full path.

Comment: actually you are right!  I like the full package reference as it helps when refactoring.  What I have just found out is that you can do a ctrl+space on the import and it offers to convert it to a package reference.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, I have posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `import 'som...'` and ctrl+space for auto-complete and get IntelliJ to make suggestion across all packages imported with pubspec and files across the project. If the file is inside a package, it will automatically insert the full path.

Comment: actually, this doesn't always work, for example with extension methods

Comment: So it cannot auto complete the filename if the file are only containing extensions? Because my answer was to this part of your question: "Is there a way to use the filename to lookup and insert an import statement with the full package address?"

Comment: yeah, that is right, if one tries to import an extension method then autoimport doesn't work. Hopefully they'll fix it soon though (unchecked the answer so others might be able to offer an answer but as it is an actual bug I checked it back!)

Comment: actually, this doesn't seem to work for me, not for extension methods or anything else